# Clickonce applications being allowed through firewall

Tags: networking, firewall, windows-firewall, visual-studio, clickonce

The company I work for uses an application that is deployed through clickonce. This means that everytime they update said program the program regenerates in a new location ie:

> C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\89XCT43D.10T\WBZ8WE7L.927\trm8..tion_1ad39bb503bcb5df_0008.0005_14829906c9aa8611\%appname%.exe

Recently the computers were updated to windows 7 machines and now everytime an update is pushed out the windows firewall see this as a new application and prompts the users to allow the program through the firewall. This means I have to walk around to every computer and type in admin credentials.

Does anyone know of a way to allow the application through windows firewall regardless of the path it is in? Google has not been very helpful so far.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818034/clickonce-applications-and-windows-firewall

Comment: @locster While that thread is related, there is still no helpful answer there.